# how to enable CCRC extension for eclipse in rad 7.0 when it's already installed on rad 8.0 in the same environment

Tags: eclipse, installation, rad, clearcase-remote-client

I have a windows XP laptop with rad 8.0 installed, RAD 7.0 as well, clearcase remote client, and clear case remote client for eclipse extension.  The CCRC eclipse extension works great in rad 8.0, but I need to enable it in rad 7.0 and the CCRC extension option is not appearing in the windows --> preferences --> team  options.   Has anyone ever had both versions of rad running on their machine before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal process would be to follow "[How to integrate CCRC Extension with Rational Application Developer](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21431847)":

[image: CCRC RAD installation]

If this isn't possible, a simple installation through the CCRC update site should work too, from any eclipse (including the one running RAD7.0). See "[Installing or updating CCRC for Eclipse and RSA](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21215611)":

[image: CCRC update site]

Comment: Note: I don't have direct experience with both RAD running with CCRC, but CCRC being a plugin like any other, it *should* support installation over multiple eclipse (here RADs).